# Spring MVC Jackson tolerant String parsing

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

Is it possible to configure `Jackson` parser in `Spring` so it would be more tolerate to given data formats in `JSON` request and automatically parse `String` to needed plain format (`Integer`, `Boolean` and etc.)?

For instance, we have bean `Request`:

```
public class Request {
     private Long field1;
     private boolean field2;
     ...
}
```

And user passes to REST method:

```
{
   "field1":"44444",
   "field2":"true"
}
```

I want to this request be parsed correctly to `Request` object. But at the same time I want to proper formatted request being parsed correctly also:

```
{
   "field1":23333,
   "field2":true
}
```

Is it possible to do **without making any changes on** `Request` class, just some settings in `context.xml` as I have dozens of such classes and do not want to change them all?

Comment: Actually I did a quick test and this is exactly the case - Spring MVC does this tolerant parsing out of the box. I used this simple bootstrap project:  https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-spring-boot.git. I can give you more details if you want to sniff around. What happens if you try it in your setup?

Comment: i think both way will be correct and jackson convert to Object